# Intstance of interface?How does this code work?

Tags: c#

Interface is not able to create instance.
But this code is work.

```
IEnumerable<string> myStr = new[]{"am", "I", "a", "Instance", "of","Interface", "?"};
```

Isn`t this code meaning create a Interface of Instance?
How does it work?

Answer (score 2):

No. The `new[]` expression that you're using creates an instance of the class `string[]`, which implements the interface `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 1):

The string array is the instance.  It just happens to implement that interface.

Answer (score 1):

The right side expression of `=` creates an instance of string array `string[]`, which implements `IEnumerable<string>`, and the instance is assigned to a variable named `myStr`, whose type is `IEnumerable<string>`. So the instance's type is `string[]`, but it behaves as `IEnumerable<string>`.

Answer (score 0):

Nope you had just assigned the string array to the interface reference it is not an instance of interface and in fact we can't initialize the instance of interface.

Below code would print `myStr`'s actual type.

```
IEnumerable<string> myStr = new[]{"am", "I", "a", "Instance", "of","Interface", "?"};
Console.WriteLine(myStr.GetType());
```

[dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6bcvvG)

As a side note you can assign any instance of class that implements the interface to the reference of that interface and that is what we call as **[polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(computer_science))**.